# MGWT Menu/Sub Menu/Drop down Panel

Tags: mgwt

I have header button left side. On Tap, I want to drop a panel or submenu. How I can do that?
Right now I am just popup dialog (with the panel) using centre().

Please help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried searching for hide/show toggle div or menu ? There are lot of workaround in there, from jQuery, pure CSS..

**Like here:** [Link!](http://www.webtutorialsource.com/tutorial/show-hide-toggle-sliding-menu-css-javascript/)

Comment: Do you mean to say, I have to use JSNI to get this functionality? No other way?

Comment: You can make a drop down menu just by CSS or with Javascript/jQuery etc. Search Dropdown menu on google.